# Why Stripe uses Map in java api

Tags: java, stripe-payments

What is the reason for using HashMap in Stripe java api?

From stripe.com:

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2";

Map<String, Object> ownerParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ownerParams.put("email", "payinguser+fill_now@example.com");

Map<String, Object> sourceParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
sourceParams.put("type", "bitcoin");
sourceParams.put("amount", 1000);
sourceParams.put("currency", "usd");
sourceParams.put("owner", ownerParams);

Source source = Source.create(sourceParams);

Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chargeParams.put("source", source.getId());
chargeParams.put("amount", source.getAmount());
chargeParams.put("currency", source.getCurrency());
Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

Why not just use simple java object with getters and setters?
(I understand that I can do my own implementation in Java because it's just http requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pattern I've seen pop up over and over. One can either:

1. Use a Map as a DTO;
2. Use MyClass extends Object (POJO) as a DTO.

There are lots of threads about this topic. [1](http://shuttrnut.in/pojo-vs-map/), [2](https://yojava.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/why-i-prefer-pojos-to-maps-for-domain-objects/), [3](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271663/use-json-objects-or-pojos-in-back-end-service).

However, what you are showing from Stripe isn't *exactly* that, they're just using the `Map` as an intermediary to stuff request attributes, before converting it into a POJO.

So, this is more like a Map used as a POJO Builder pattern. The alternative then would be:

```
Source source = new Source.Builder()
    .withType(type)
    .withAmount(amount)
    .build();
```

Which is what I would prefer and is how most everything at AWS (for example) works.

But I think it's more straightforward from a JSON serializer perspective to convert a Map, then to add a bunch of syntactic fluff and framework-y stuff to a POJO. So, basically -- just an implementation decision.

Also, if your API has a high quantity of request attributes compared to a small number of request objects, then they start to resemble dictionaries of fields more than they do structured data, I suppose.

Lest we forget that after all of our fancy Java nonsense, this is going to be a String dictionary in JSON anyway. So truly, #YOLO.

Comment: I would also prefer Builder over Map. You can add java doc to methods, internal validation and so on. Stripe produces high quality software and it was strange to me to see that Map in their Java library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact details but reason seems to be very simple. They want to avoid setting & getting each and every property instead they used, Map to get keys and values set accordingly. They are most probably dealing with JSON. Well, even if it's XML, using a Map is much easier than handling via plain Object, since every time you have to manually set and get each property you require. On the contrary, many properties can be optional so just set values which are passed via map since it's easier to iterate over map than an object.

Comment: When you look at Stripe API and everything they do it becomes obvious that they don't do things just to make them done the simplest way they can. They try to make their staff very easy to use. Which means they think that from client's point of view it's easier to maintain Map instead of Object with getters and setters. And I don't understand why.